# Is there a way to send a filter to a Sharepoint List and view the results in a web part?

Tags: sharepoint

I've been tasked with setting up an advanced filter for a customer facing portal - as part of this, I have filters set up for various tags such as Priority, Site, Application, Reference.  I've come up with a way to generate a URL that goes to the list and sets the filters to the selections given, by giving an html navigation command using a JavaScript function to splice together the URL.

This works fine for use within my team, however customers shouldn't have full access to our lists, and we have a customer-facing portal that currently has a limited view of these lists displayed to them, with much fewer details and none of our internal notes.  These limited views are done through a web part that displays the Soaped in view - this is where I'm wanting to have the filtered list show up, as it's a more user-friendly way to search the list for information that the customer would want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Query String (URL) Filler Wepart to the page, configure it for the param in the URL and configure connection or the List WebPart to receive filter value from the Query String Filler.

1. Add QSF webpart: 
   [image]
2. Configure the WP:
   [image]
3. Establish Connection (go to the WP Edit mode first)
   [image]
4. Test the URL param: ...sharepoint.com/sites/dev/SitePages/TestPage.aspx?Disp=1